# Python: sys.modules key points to different module then the one it should originally point to

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, sys

On Python 3.8.10 I observe the following:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.27.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: keys = sorted([key for key in sys.modules if 'lino_medico.lib.courses' in key])
   ...: modules = tuple(
   ...:     m
   ...:     for m in map(sys.modules.__getitem__, keys)
   ...: )

In [3]: keys
Out[3]: 
['lino_medico.lib.courses',
 'lino_medico.lib.courses.desktop',
 'lino_medico.lib.courses.models']

In [4]: sys.modules[keys[-1]]
Out[4]: <module 'lino_medico.lib.courses.desktop' from '/home/blurry/lino/env/repositories/medico/lino_medico/lib/courses/desktop.py'>

In [5]: sys.modules['lino_medico.lib.courses.models']
Out[5]: <module 'lino_medico.lib.courses.desktop' from '/home/blurry/lino/env/repositories/medico/lino_medico/lib/courses/desktop.py'>

In [6]: from importlib import import_module

In [7]: import_module(keys[-1])
Out[7]: <module 'lino_medico.lib.courses.desktop' from '/home/blurry/lino/env/repositories/medico/lino_medico/lib/courses/desktop.py'>

In [8]: keys[-1]
Out[8]: 'lino_medico.lib.courses.models'

In [9]: import weakref

In [10]: isinstance(import_module(keys[-1]), weakref.ProxyTypes)
Out[10]: False
```

If you look at the keys in `Out[3]:` the last module name is `'lino_medico.lib.courses.models'` but in `Out[4]:` as well as in `Out[5]:` and `Out[7]:` the key points to the file `.../lino_medico/lib/courses/desktop.py` instead of `.../lino_medico/lib/courses/models.py`.

I am feeling out of my league here. Any help would be appreciated on explaining how this can happen.

Comment: I've cleaned up tags and the reference to Django, since this doesn't appear to be related to Django at all. Note that you can rollback the edit if you disagree with this change.

Comment: Looking at your self-answer, I am totally confused by the question now. It seems you are asking specifically about a custom library; this library seems not publicly available and the question shows nothing of it. There is no way for anyone but yourself to answer the question, and no way for anyone but yourself to benefit from the Q&A for related issues. While [it is fine to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), both question and answer should still be proper posts by themselves as per the [ask] and related help pages.

Comment: Please strongly consider to [edit] your question to include all relevant information for it to stand on its own and to allow people with similar problems to identify this. See the [ask] and [mre] help pages as a starting point on what such debugging questions should provide on [so].

Comment: You are right @MisterMiyagi, My answer would not mean much to outsiders that does not know our [software packages](https://www.lino-framework.org/) but it should be meaningful to our team members, who has links to this in our ticketing system. And also I could have managed it in our own ticketing system, But since I put the question here out of frustration, it should stay this way. I will provide as much info as I can.

Answer (score -1):

As it turned out there was a bug ([source of the bug here](https://gitlab.com/lino-framework/lino/-/blob/0d168d58411e098e4dc4603a0776f1be91231d16/lino/core/site.py#L1832)) on our code.

```
m = import_module(mn)
self.models[p.app_label].__dict__.update(m.__dict__)
```

Here, we were updating the `models.__dict__` from `desktop.py` (where `mn` is the `desktop.py`). Which had some attributes like `__name__`, `__spec__`, `__loader__`, `__file__` and such that were being overwritten.

Solution:

```
m = import_module(mn)
d = m.__dict__.copy()
for key in m.__dict__:
    if key.startswith('__'):
        d.pop(key)
self.models[p.app_label].__dict__.update(d)
```

I just had to remove anything that starts with a double underscore (`__`). [solution code](https://gitlab.com/lino-framework/lino/-/blob/f7cee025c2d598904def4ea972463361af67562f/lino/core/site.py#L1832).